# Using date range picker for Facebook Marketing API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, date-range, facebook-marketing-api

I am starting to think this can't be done. I currently have Facebook Marketing API and all works well when I place in a set period of time like minus 1 month from today. But, I want to have a bootstrap date range picker to pick the time ranges for my clients. So, in the $params variable is the time_range that I am trying to work with.

Or even something different I can do whatever works would be awesome.

All I need is for the API take the dates and use that for the insights from Facebook. I am using ajax call that sends the _POST startDate and endDate to store into their own variables $startDate/$endDate and when I try the code out nothing gets echoed back. Below is the AJAX call which works cause I have used it in other section of the web app. And second section of code is the Marketing API code.

AJAX CALL FILE.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#config-demo').click(function() {
                  $(this).parent().find('#demo').click();
                });
                updateConfig();

                function updateConfig() {
                  var options = {

                       "showDropdowns": true,

                  };
                  options.opens = "center";



                options.ranges = {
                      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                      'Last 14 Days': [moment().subtract(13, 'days'), moment()],
                      'Last 28 Days': [moment().subtract(27, 'days'), moment()],
                      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                };

                  $('#config-demo').daterangepicker(options, function(start, end, label) { 
                        var startDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
                        var endDate = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        passDate(startDate, endDate);

                   });
                }
        });

        function passDate(startDate,endDate) {
            $('.loader').show();
            $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use
                    url: 'fb_daterange.php', // the url where we want to POST
                    dataType: 'json', // Our data object
                    data: {startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate} // Ensure we pass the start and end dates to $_POST in PHP
                })

                // using the done promise callback
                .done(function(data) {
                    console.log('done callback - data: ',data);
                    $('.loader').hide();
                    alert('yoyoyo');
                    $('#fbdata').text(data.message1); // log data to the console so we can see
                });
        }
```

MARKETING API FILE WHERE AJAX SENDS THE DATES TO..

```
<?php 

if((!empty($_POST['startDate'])&&(!empty($_POST['endDate'])))) {    // Check whether the date is empty


    //setup variables for start and end date..
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['startDate']));
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['endDate']));

$account = new AdAccount('act_xxxxxxxxxxxx');


        $params = array(
          'time_range' => ("{'since': '".$startDate."', 'until': '".$endDate."'}"),

          'level' => 'ad',
          'limit' => '20',
        );

$fields = array(
  AdsInsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
  AdsInsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_ID,
  AdsInsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
  AdsInsightsFields::UNIQUE_CLICKS,
  AdsInsightsFields::REACH,
  AdsInsightsFields::SPEND,
  AdsInsightsFields::TOTAL_ACTIONS,
);

$insights = $account->getInsights($fields, $params);
foreach($insights as $i) {
    $impress = number_format((float)$i->impressions);
    $reach = number_format((float)$i->reach);
    $totalAction = number_format((float)$i->total_actions);
    $i->campaign_id;
    $i->campaign_name;
    $impress;
    $i->unique_clicks;
    $reach;
    $i->spend;
    $totalAction;
}       
$return['message1'] = $startDate;
echo $startDate;

            header('Content-Type: text/json');              
            echo json_encode($return); //echo response back to Home page... 
}   
 ?>
```

The part I am getting stuck on is I think the $params with time_range because when I comment all the marketing api code out and use something else to send like $t = "hello";  and use the date range picker on the web app it sends the information over.

Comment: I am adding this whether it helps or not but, I am still trying to get this to work. So, again when trying to comment out all the marketing api code and just my own simple variables like $t ="hello"; to see if it prints out when I select a date and it does. So, I started to remove some lines of code from the comment like the $account = new AdAccount('act_xxxxxx'); When I uncomment this line the simple variable trick does not display when I select a date. So, I wonder if this is the cause of the whole thing is there some type of security feature built in to ajax calls or something.

Comment: Anyone able to figure what I might be doing wrong here please anyone.